# bluetooth search and receive sms

Tags: bluetooth, sms, java-me

Can the bluetooth search run while checking if any SMS messages have been received?

When I try to check if there is a new SMS by the command `msg = smsconn.receive()`, the program will not go back to search for bluetooth devices. Meaning that I can't get it to check for SMS while running the bluetooth search.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [Java ME](http://java.sun.com/javame/index.jsp)? Sounds like you need two seperate [threads](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) in your application so that you can run processes concurrently. Of course it would help if you could give some samples of the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do two things at once when programming (well its technically not two things at once but the quick explaination is that it is) is through the use of threads.